# Ansible on Windows: become / become_user permission/owner problems

Tags: windows, ansible, file-permissions, ansible-2.x

I want to perform some actions, that do not require using the Administrator account. For example, cloning a git repo or creating a folder.

I tried this:

```
  - name: Create gogo1 directory
    win_shell: mkdir c:\tmp\gogo1
    become: yes
    become_user: vagrant
    vars:
      ansible_become_pass: vagrant
```

This creates the desired directoy, but when I am logged in as user vagrant and try to remove it I get:

> You'll need to provide administrator permission to delete this folder.

The user Vagrant is not given any permissions to the folder gogo1.
I need to do this in addition:

```
  - name: Change owner of gogo1
    win_owner:
      path: c:\tmp\gogo1
      user: vagrant
      recurse: yes
```

Using `win_psexec` works as intended. It creates the directory, gives user vagrant the permissions, and thus I can delete it without being prompted with the above message.

```
- name: Create gogo2 directory
    win_psexec: 
      command: cmd /k "cd c:\tmp && mkdir gogo && exit"
      username: vagrant
      password: vagrant
```

How can I use `become` and `become_user` to create a folder (or do clone a git repo) and giving the user all necessary permissions and ownership (like `win_psexec` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For become to work as you want you need it to login interactively so the profile for the user is loaded when the folder is created.

To do this you can try to set the login_flags (Ansible 2.5+) on become like so:

```yaml
- name: Create gogo1 directory
  win_shell: mkdir c:\tmp\gogo1
  become: yes
  become_user: vagrant
  become_flags: logon_type=interactive logon_flags=with_profile
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: vagrant
```

You can read all the specifics on **become_flags** here:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html